# vector implementation and data member definition

Tags: c, vector, data-structures, dynamic-arrays

In a number of vector implementations which I've seen, the following definition of vector structure is used:

```
struct vector {
   void **data;
   int size;
   int count;
};
```

Why do we need pointer-to-pointer member here?

Comment: Probably it makes resizing easier. If you use a straight pointer, and you have copies of the vector everywhere, it's very hard, if possible, to update all copies of the pointer. However, if all copies shares the same pointer, and use a pointer to that pointer as a reference, then changing the "shared" pointer automatically synchronizes all copies of the vector.

Comment: @user3528438 wrong, it is useless to sync the pointer while the count remains unsynced.

Comment: BTW: can you provide a sample implementation that you've seen?

Answer (score 3):

Because it can be a vector of pointer elements which can have any type (*including pointers*) since `void *` is convertible to any pointer type in [c](/questions/tagged/c)<sup>1</sup>. Also, elements will be separated by the size of a pointer making it simpler to work with.

You can then get the actual value by dereferencing the `void *` pointer to the element after casting to the appropriate pointer type or simply getting a pointer if the elements are pointers.

Sample implementation (*far from complete of course*<sup>2</sup>)

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct vector
{
    void **data;
    size_t count;
    size_t size;
};

void
vector_new(struct vector *vector, size_t size, size_t nmemb)
{
    vector->data = NULL;
    vector->count = 0;
    vector->size = size;
}

void
vector_push_back(struct vector *vector, void *value)
{
    unsigned char **data;    
    data = realloc(vector->data, sizeof(*data) * (vector->count + 1));
    if (data == NULL)
        return; // Probably return an error indicator
    vector->data = (void *) data;

    data[vector->count] = malloc(vector->size);
    if (data[vector->count] == NULL)
        return; // Probably return an error indicator
    memcpy(data[vector->count], value, vector->size);
    vector->count++;
}

void *
vector_get(struct vector *vector, size_t index)
{
    return (unsigned char *) vector->data[index];
}

int
main(void)
{
    struct vector vector;

    vector_new(&vector, sizeof(float), 100);

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i)
    {
        float value;
                value = (float) rand() / RAND_MAX;
        fprintf(stdout, "vector[%d] %f\n", i, value);
        vector_push_back(&vector, &value);
    }

    fprintf(stdout, "Read them to check!\n");

    for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; ++i)
    {
        float value;
        value = *(float *) vector_get(&vector, i);
        fprintf(stdout, "vector[%d] %f\n", i, value);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>This kind of construction is generally a bad design choice since it's quite hard to maintain and it's harder to write accessor functions. Nevertheless there are geniune use cases for it of course. The [c](/questions/tagged/c) language should not be used for generic typing, trying to enforce that has usually less benefits than problems.</sub>

<sup>2</sup><sub>It lacks a free/destroy function for example.</sub>

Comment: Also nothing fancy has to be going on here, if you *are* using C then having a vector library based on something like this isn't a terrible idea, it's not trying to out-do a language with better "generic" typing.

Comment: I mean *NORMALLY*, of course there are cases where it's the correct choice.

Comment: @Veltas In general it is. From my experience, when you see someone trying to make a generic vector for generic type, they need [tag:c++]. Doing it in [tag:c] will end up being a pain in the ... . But of course there are situations where you could need it, but an expert [tag:c] programmer would probably use a `union` instead of  a `void` pointer. I have done that myself when writing a small [tag:c] *.ods* file reader library for a larger project, I used a *union* and it was elegant simple and useful. But most of the time it's not needed.

Comment: I am not making it a language discussion, but you need to consider *WHO* is going to want to have that feature. If it's an experienced programmer then they know what they're doing otherwise another language would be more appropriate. Please do not answer this comment, you downvoted and that does express your opinion just fine. Although I tried to point out that I didn't mean that it's *always bad*, it seems that I wasn't able to communicate that so further discussing this is just a waste of time. Thank your for your comments and opinion.

Comment: I don't think it's fair to say one should not write a generic vector-like set of functions in C. You say you've seen problems with it, well I've also written such things myself and they've worked well for me: not cluttering the code, not unsafe, etc.  Don't tell me not to comment.

Comment: So should we remove `qsort` from C because it's generic code?

Comment: @iharob, before downvoting :), I'd like to understand your line of thoughts. Short of compiler change (which of course in not possible in multiple cases) what are the alternatives?

Answer (score 0):

See a nice recap of functionality expected of a `vector` at [vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/) (the link goes to `vector` in C++, but the information on their functionality applies to `vector` in general, in C or C++ or any other language for that matter).

Salient points are abstracted below. The functionality gives you clues about why the data structure is the way it is.

> Vectors are sequence containers representing arrays that can change in
>   size.
>
> Just like arrays ... their elements can also be accessed using offsets
>   on regular pointers to its elements ... But unlike arrays, their size
>   can change dynamically ...
>
> ... vector containers may allocate some extra storage to accommodate
>   for possible growth ... and thus, vectors do not reallocate each time
>   an element is added to the container.

```
struct vector {
   void **data; // needs to act like an array of pointers i.e. void *data[]
   int size;    // actual memory allocated may be in access of count
   int count;   // current count of elements in data
};
```

Comment: [tag:c++] has templates which would solve the type issue. And AFAIK `std::vector` is a template class so the [tag:c++] compiler creates a *different* class when you instantiate the template with a given type. In [tag:c] this would work in a different way.

Comment: Yes it would. The link is just for information on vectors. Which is the same in C and C++.

Answer (score -2):

It's quite common. You can treat it as:

```
char *data[size];
```

So each element is a string, or any storage type which size is unknown until runtime. For example`int i=123; 
data=malloc(sizeof(int));
memcpy(data, &i, sizeof(i));`

Comment: You can't treat them same . One is pointer to pointer and other is array of pointers(_not same_).

Comment: You didn't improve it. A string is not  a pointer, a pointer can point to a string but that's not what you said.

Comment: @ameyCU it just for better understanding for those who is confused by **

Comment: @XQ.Wei Okay , but instead giving one more type is not correct IMHO . If confusion is about  `char **` better to clear about `char **` :-)

Comment: @XQ.Wei Ignoring array/pointer differences, treating a `void **` like a `char **` is not standardised. Cast to a `char **` explicitly, maybe explain this or be careful around it.

Comment: @ameyCU the nature of C language expects programmer to do every garbage collection manually and so that's why it became antique.

Comment: @XQ.Wei: Calling C "antique" is quite inappropriate. We still use hammers, allthough they have been used for thousands of years. C still has its benefits. But not every problem is a nail.

Comment: @Olaf I myself prefer C language in a wide application range, while my boss doesn't agree much because he wants an easy recruiting with a quality coding control, so I have to use C# or Java, officially.

Comment: @XQ.Wei: The plethora of rubbish Java and C# code is a clear indicator bad programmers can mess up code in any language. OTOH C code can be pretty clear if written by a good developer (and deveploment does not take longer). For some applications even much clearer than a zoo of classes & spaghetti-inheritance.

Comment: @XQ.Wei Preferring java or c# over C , they may have their reason but "anitique" ? IMHO , I think C is one of the most powerful language but that's not the discussion here :)